# What happens to a creature enchanted with totem armor if both are destroyed at the same time?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If a player controls a [Boon Satyr](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Boon%20Satyr) enchanted with [Hyena Umbra](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hyena%20Umbra) providing totem armor, and an opponent plays [Fracturing Gust](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fracturing%20Gust) to destroy all artifacts and more importantly enchantments. What happens?

An aura with Totem armor replaces destruction of the enchanted creature with destruction of the aura itself. [Boon satyr](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Boon%20satyr) is an enchantment creature.

This question may become more important due to the printing of [End Hostilities](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=End%20Hostilities).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the rulings for hyena umbra:

> If a spell or ability (such as Planar Cleansing) would destroy both an Aura with totem armor and the permanent it's enchanting at the same time, totem armor's effect will save the enchanted permanent from being destroyed. Instead, the spell or ability will destroy the Aura in two different ways at the same time, but the result is the same as destroying it once.

Comment: The 'basically what happens' revision is completely incorrect.  The 'effect' of destroying permanents (i.e., the effect of the resolution of the spell) never goes on the stack, and totem armor isn't a triggered ability; it's a replacement ability.  (You can tell it's not a triggered ability because it doesn't follow the templating for triggered ability, and you can tell it's a replacement ability because it follows that templating: 'if... instead...')

Comment: By effect I meant the spell, sorry. And yes good point, I didn't realise that.

Answer (score 6):

For both Fracturing Gust and End Hostilities, only Hyena Umbra will get destroyed.

---

Both

> Destroy all Enchantments.

and

> Destroy all creatures and all permanents attached to creatures.

are effectively

> Destroy Boon Satyr and Hyena Umbra.

There's only one instruction to destroy, so everything is destroyed simultaneously.

The Umbra's ability modifies that instruction

> Remove all damage from Boon Satyr and destroy Hyena Umbra and Hyena Umbra.

It's impossible for the effect to destroy Hyena Umbra twice, so it only does it once<sup>[CR 400.6]</sup><sup>[1]</sup>.

> Remove all damage from Boon Satyr and destroy Hyena Umbra.

So, you remove all damage from Boon Satyr and destroy Hyena Umbra<sup>[2]</sup>.

This is supported by a ruling on the Umbras

> If a spell or ability (such as Planar Cleansing) would destroy both an Aura with totem armor and the permanent it's enchanting at the same time, totem armor's effect will save the enchanted permanent from being destroyed. Instead, the spell or ability will destroy the Aura in two different ways at the same time, but the result is the same as destroying it once.

---

1. This means that only a single regeneration shield is needed to save Hyena Umbra.
2. Only one Enchantment was destroyed, so you gain two life from the remainder of Fracturing Gust's ability.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought you'd need two regeneration shields to save it. Because while there two destroy effects on it, they both happen at the same time and not one then the other. So wouldn't you need one?

Comment: @Cameron, Like you said, there are two destroy effects. They both happen even though they happen at the same time.

Comment: @Cameron I thought this short discussion was interesting enough to warrant its own question, [here](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/18783/6692).

Comment: @Rainbolt, Oh the irony. I made the comment based on my incorrect memory of [this thread](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/3436546), the very thread you posted to prove me wrong. In case you didn't notice, I'm the one who found and posted the relevant rule at the bottom of the thread. Fixed.