# If a single effect would destroy a permanent multiple times, can regeneration replace it?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-regenerate

Nancy controls a [Runeclaw Bear](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Runeclaw%20Bear) enchanted by [Hyena Umbra](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hyena%20Umbra). Hyena Umbra has a regeneration shield, granted by [Reknit](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Reknit). Anthony casts [Planar Cleansing](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Planar%20Cleansing). This causes two replacement effects to apply. According to rule 616, Nancy gets to choose the order in which they apply.

> **616.1.** If two or more replacement effects are attempting to modify the way an event affects an object, the affected object's controller chooses one to apply [...]

> **616.1d** Once the chosen effect has been applied, this process is repeated [...]

If Nancy chooses to apply Totem Armor first, and then Regeneration Shield, does Hyena Umbra survive?

Comment: Choosing the same target twice for Decimate might have been a simpler example. :)

Comment: Nancy gets a warning for trying to cast a sorcery on Anthony's turn and the game state is reverted to before the illegal action. :)

Comment: @Affe I can't believe I messed that up. I was trying to start a thing where people on this site speak in terms of active and non-active player, just like the judge tests, and completely botched it. Oh well. It's fixed now.

Comment: I don't quite understand the situation asked in this post, but this ruling on Austere Command may be useful regarding one effect causing destruction multiple times: "If the first and third mode are chosen, an artifact creature with converted mana cost 3 or less would be destroyed twice by this spell. It would have to be regenerated twice to survive. (A similar thing happens with most of the other combinations)"

Comment: @Kevin Austere Command is different, modal spells are kinda funny.  It created two effects that you execute in the order printed on the card.  "Destroy all artifacts.  (then) Destroy all enchantments."  It's not the same as, e.g., "Destroy all artifacts and enchantments" which is a single effect applying twice (that gets converted to a single destruction by rule 400.6).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I copied the answer from [here](http://community.wizards.com/comment/42883556#comment-42883556), where a similar question was answered by Daniel Kitachewsky. Daniel is a high-level Judge from France, and the goto-guy when judges don't know the answer.

> Planar Cleansing resolves and destroys all creatures, artifacts and enchantments.
>   I have a Runeclaw Bears enchanted with Boar Umbra.
>
> The replacement effect of the totem armor saves the Bears, but if I have a way to regenerate the totem armor, will I have to regenerate it once or twice?

If there are two regeneration shields, the Bear Umbra is regenerated no matter what.

If there's only one regeneration shield on it, it gets more complicated:
- If the same player controls Runeclaw Bear and Bear Umbra, that player may choose whether the Bear Umbra is destroyed or not.
- If the active player controls Runeclaw Bear and the nonactive player controls Bear Umbra, the Bear Umbra is regenerated.
- If the active player controls Bear Umbra and the nonactive player controls Runeclaw Bear, the Bear Umbra is destroyed.

Now for more detail:

What happens is that we have an event that's trying to move objects from one zone to another, and some replacement effects trying to change that event. Moreover, when two effects try to do mutually exclusive things to an object, such as destroying it twice, only one of these effects continues to exists, before being modified by further replacement effects.

A. In the scenario where one player controls both Runeclaw Bear and Bear Umbra, the event looks like this:

A1. Destroy Runeclaw Bear, destroy Bear Umbra

Two things try to replace this, regenerating the Bear Umbra and replacing destroying Runeclaw Bear by destroying Bear Umbra. The controller chooses which replacement effect to apply first; we'll see later if the other effect is still applicable.

- If the controller chooses to apply regeneration first, we get

  A2a. Destroy Runeclaw Bear, tap Bear Umbra

  replaced thanks to totem armor by

  A3a. Destroy Bear Umbra, tap Bear Umbra

  ultimately destroying Bear Umbra.
- If the controller chooses to apply totem armor first, we get

  A2b. Destroy Bear Umbra, destroy Bear Umbra

  modified into

  A3b. Destroy Bear Umbra

  because destroying an object twice is impossible, then replaced by

  A4b. Tap Bear Umbra

  And it's not destroyed!

  B. If Runeclaw Bear and Bear Umbra are controlled by different players, we fall into one of the scenarios above, but we don't choose which one.

  The active player applies the replacement effect trying to replace the event that affects the object he contols first, then the nonactive player gets to have his replacement effects.

  So:
- If the active player controls Runeclaw Bear and the nonactive player controls Bear Umbra, we first apply totem armor, then remove one of the "destroy Bear Umbra" effects, then regenerate it.
- If the active player controls Bear Umbra and the nonactive player controls Runeclaw Bear, we first regenerate Bear Umbra, then apply totem armor, thus destroying Bear Umbra.

Comment: Bear Umbra? is that a typo or a different card?

Comment: @Pow-Ian It's a different card. I don't understand "When two effects try to do mutually exclusive things to an object, such as destroying it twice, **only one of these effects continues to exist**, before being modified by further replacement effects." Where did the part in bold come from?

Comment: CR 400.6. "that object’s controller—or its owner if it has no controller—chooses which effect to apply"

Answer (score 3):

Ok, expanding on the line of reasoning from Ikegami in that [other question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/18775/what-happens-to-a-creature-enchanted-with-totem-armor-if-both-are-destroyed-at-t), the events produced by [Planar Cleansing](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPlanar%20Cleansing%5d):

> Destroy all nonland permanents

are effectively

> Destroy [Runeclaw Bear](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRuneclaw%20Bear%5d) and destroy [Hyena Umbra](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHyena%20Umbra%5d)

Totem armor can replace the first event:

> (Remove all damage from Runeclaw Bear and destroy Hyena Umbra) and destroy Hyena Umbra.

but the lone regeneration shield can only replace one of the "destroy Hyena Umbra" events. It doesn't matter which. The result then becomes:

> Remove all damage from Runeclaw Bear and remove all damage from Hyena Umbra and tap it and destroy Hyena Umbra.

So Hyena Umbra is destroyed.

If you aren't convinced that the two destruction events are treated separately, rule 400.6 clearly states that they are:

> Note that multiple instances of the same thing may be mutually exclusive; for example, two simultaneous “destroy” effects.

Comment: For some reason, I got it in my head that "Destroy Hyena Umbra and Destroy Hyena Umbra" would collapse into a single event since you can only logically destroy something once.

Comment: @Rainbolt - I'm pretty sure there are no comp. rules about simplifying effects using Boolean logic. ;)

Comment: But this is exactly my point. How did you *know* there were two separate effects to begin with? You used Boolean logic to explain your case, and then disqualified my response on the basis of using boolean logic!

Comment: @Rainbolt I think the idea is that the steps in the explanation are how you know there are two. Before applying the totem armor replacement effect, there are two things happening: the Bear is being destroyed, and the Umbra is being destroyed. After applying it, the former is replaced with the Umbra being destroyed - there are still two, unless the rules provide some way to simplify things.

Comment: @Jefromi You're right. I removed my counterexample since it was incorrect.

Comment: I finally found a relevant rule at the bottom of [this thread](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/3436546) and added it to your answer. The Level 3 judge in that thread who posted comment #20 seems to disagree with this answer, and that makes me uneasy. If nothing new comes up in the next week, and you haven't made any more sarcastic retorts, I'll probably accept this answer.

Comment: @Rainbolt - Kitachewsky's answer from that thread should be correct. He's actually Level 4 now and is one of the sources for "official" judge rulings. You should write up a new answer and accept that one.

Comment: Hao Ye, I have changed the answer to which you linked based as a result of my answer in the thread Rainbolt linked. I was actually thinking of that very thread when I made my comment in the answer you linked, but I remembered the conclusion incorrectly.

Comment: @ikegami So what is the verdict? I'm not sure that after all of this discussion, a clear outcome has been reached. Believe me, I read that entire thread, and was left wondering why it conflicted with the rule you quoted. Perhaps it doesn't conflict because that rule isn't applicable to this situation? I just can't copy the L4 judge's answer without reconciling it with what I already know first.

Comment: If I understand correctly comment #20 of that other thread is actually the most complete and correct answer. And rule 400.6 is actually the reason why it becomes only one destruction event and not two.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Planar Cleansing will try to destroy everything at the same time. Hyena Umbra gets two destroy effects from Planar Cleansing.

However, these both happen at the same time (not one after the other), and Regeneration is the next TIME this permanent would be destroyed. Once regeneration has saved it, both destroy effects have passed because they both tried to destroy it at the same time.

If the destroy effects were one after the other, then you would need more regeneration shields.

Comment: Hyena Umbra actually gets one destroy effect from itself and one from Planar Cleansing. Bear lives - Hyena dies.

Comment: Yeah but they happen at the same time.

Comment: Cameron, actually they would go on the stack in the order chosen by the controller of Hyena Umbra.

Comment: Effects (and, in particular, replacement effects) don't go on the stack. In some cases they get *applied* in an order chosen by the controller, but that's not the same.